# org.apache.kafka.clients.producer does not exist

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Need help with kafka. Im really new to Kafka and i just started learning.
I'm getting this issue when I'm following a tutorial.

Package org.apache.kafka.clients.producer does not exist.
I'm using NetBeans if that gives any clues.

Any clues and help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Which package manager have you ? Maven ?

Comment: You have to provide `kafka-clients` library dependency while running your java code. You can download it from [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.kafka/kafka-clients)

Comment: Thanks @avr. this solved my problem!